# Renaming php file in PhpStorm don`t work after forgot the extension

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

I have a problem with PhpStorm.

I created a file `BlogPost` and forgot to write the `.php` extension.

I renamed the file (`BlogPost.php`) but the file was not recognized (in editor the PHP code was like a  plain text). I deleted the file and created again as a PHP file the same thing.

If I rename the file something else everything is OK. If rename it back to `BlogPost.php` the file is not recognized.

Where in PhpStorm keep tracks of this .... history ?

I am using PhpStorm 2018.1.

Comment: Are you using GIT? If so, just revert your changes.

Comment: *"I created a file BlogPost and forgot to write the .php extension. "* 1) So you have used `New | File`. Next time use dedicated `New | PHP Class` or `PHP File` -- they will add `.php` extension automatically. 2) After you create a file with no extension .. IDE will show a small screen where it offer to choose File Type associated with such file (by default it will be Text file). You must have accepted that dialog without checking it through -- the reason for almost all "my file is treated as plain text" cases.

Comment: 3) As a result, IDE have created `BlogPost` pattern associated with Text file type... which is more precise than generic `*.php`. Solution to that problem you already know. So next time -- please pay a bit more attention to what's happening on the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Settings | Editor | File Types | Text.

Comment: not in my dreams i was thinking that phpstorm put the file BlogPost.php in Text section. Removed the file from there and now works. Thx a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

The phpstorm extension itself performs like an external class feature which extends the elements from the BlogPost the root function.
Simply renaming the script will results in class name mismatch.
Since you didn't post any code here. It's very hard to be sure what exactly the problem is.

Your best bet is to call the debug feature in phpstorm 2018.1 and try to add a try catch in between the function to figures out which segment of code is causing the existing problem.